# How to get a button to toggle another button on a separate form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to get it so when a person in the administration panel pushes the "Lock System" on the admin form it disables the buttons on "Form1". I have set the button to `public` and changed it to a public void in the code.

Here is what I have tried.

Admin Panel Code:

```
private void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Form1)this.Owner).button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

`Form1` Code:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newwindow = new CanCad();
    newwindow.Show();
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error I get: http://prntscr.com/ptkkm3

Comment: `newwindow.Show(this);`

Comment: Did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the `Owner` property of the second form but it was never set. To set the `Owner` property, you should pass the instance of the first form to the `.Show()` method:

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newwindow = new CanCad();
    newwindow.Show(this); // <------ notice the difference.
}
```

Or you could set the property manually if you like:

```
newwindow.Owner = this;
newwindow.Show();
```

Then, you can use your original code in the second form as usual:

```
private void Button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Form1)this.Owner).button1.Enabled = false;
}
```

A further improvement would be to use the [`as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator) to make sure that the owner is of the right type:

```
Form1 frm = this.Owner as Form1;
if (frm != null) frm.button1.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: Ok I did that and the error doesnt show up but the button still does not disable. I placed that code in the admin panel side.

Comment: Button1 is a button on form1 that when clicked opens the next form. I want it so that if the admin presses the "Disable CAD" button it makes Button1 ON form1 disabled

Comment: Yes when you click the button on form1 it opens a new form called CanCad. I apologize I am new to c#

Comment: Sorry, I got them mixed up. Here's my question... when you click the button on the `CanCad` form, is that instance of `CanCad` opened by the `Button1_Click` event handler of Form1 or using something else? Your current code doesn't reproduce the problem. Please read how you can provide a [repro].

Comment: Ok so here is form1: http://prntscr.com/ptksb0

The button "CanCad" is the button I am trying to toggle.

The button "Admin Panel" takes you to a login screen then to another form where the "disable CanCad" button is

Hope this helps

Comment: If you want to disable button change false to true... And to see that change You need also call this.Invalidate() to re-draw form...

Comment: @Kuda Do where does the ` this.Invalidate()` go?